# how can I use navigation.navigate("Login") within the login function

Tags: react-native

This is my Home page code

```js
const HomePage = ({navigation}) =>{

    const login=()=>{
        
    }
    return(
        <View>
        <ToolBar title="Home Page"></ToolBar>
        <MyButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")} title="Register"></MyButton>
        </View>
    )
}


export default HomePage;
```

here I want to use the `login` function to `onPress()`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```js
const login=()=>{
    //write any logic or API call
    navigation.navigate("Login")
}
```

And in `return` call it like:

```js
<MyButton onPress={() => login()} title="Register" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HomePage = ({navigation}) => {

  const login = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Login")
  }

  return(
    <View>
      <ToolBar title="Home Page"></ToolBar>
      <MyButton onPress={login} title="Register"></MyButton>
    </View>
  )

}

export default HomePage;
```